# Khan academy, towers of hanoi recursion

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Challenge Solve hanoi recursively

I cannot get past stage 2 of this challenge, which is a shame as it means I can't coimplete anything.  Can anyone help?

The link is here:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/towers-of-hanoi/p/challenge-solve-hanoi-recursively

**The questions asks the following:**

Make a recursive function call to move the disks sitting on top of the bottom disk on the fromPeg to the spare peg, i.e. move (numDisks - 1) disks to the spare peg.

You can find the spare peg by using the getSparePeg function.

A call to hanoi.getSparePeg(peg1,peg2) returns the remaining peg that isn't peg1 or peg2.

**The hint says this:**

// recursive case:

```
var sparePeg = hanoi.getSparePeg(fromPeg, toPeg);
solveHanoi();
```

But despite all that, even though it only seems to ask for the solveHanoi() to be filled out with the parameters, it wont progress. Do I have to seperately declare the fromPeg, and toPeg, and assign them letters?

**Below is a rough stab at the code:**

```
var solveHanoi = function(numDisks, fromPeg, toPeg) {
    if (numDisks===0)
    {
       return;
    }
};    
var fromPeg="A";
var toPeg="B";
var sparePeg = hanoi.getSparePeg(fromPeg,toPeg);
//solveHanoi(5, "A","B");
//Program.assertEqual(hanoi.isSolved("B"),true);
```

Comment: Isn't Khan academy a page to learn stuff? What's the point in helping you solve their questions?

Comment: Because I'm hopelessly stuck and will have to abandon the topic if I can't get past this stage. If you can't complete stage 2, you cant do stage 3 4 and 5. I've spent hours on it already and its a big waste.  I didn't want to make trouble, I'd just love to know what I'm required to do here.

Comment: I know what your intention is, but KA is about to learn stuff. If you can't solve the task of stage 2, you need to practise. And the Towers of Hanoi is a well documented problem, so through doing some research, you should be able to find a generic solution

Comment: try [this explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution).

Comment: I read the link from Will Ness above, this is fine as far as it goes, but my problem is not a theoretical one about solving the puzzle, its a very immediate one about what exactly is the variable name they are looking for, ie there is some syntax they want that I can't figure out.

Comment: Here is a solution that worked:var solveHanoi = function(numDisks, fromPeg, toPeg) {
    // base case:  no disks to move
    if(numDisks === 0){
        return;
    }
    // recursive case:
    var sparePeg = hanoi.getSparePeg(fromPeg, toPeg);
    
    solveHanoi(numDisks-1, fromPeg, sparePeg);
    hanoi.moveDisk(fromPeg,toPeg);
    solveHanoi(numDisks-1, sparePeg, toPeg);
};